# Вывести посадочную страницу в Yii

Tags: php, yii

Подкинули задачку: к существующему сайту прикрутить посадочную страницу, которая будет выводится по абсолютно другому шаблону. Через `views` как рекомендуют здесь пробовал, но во первых, лэйаут используется тот же что и на остальных страницах, во вторых не смог соорудить правило, чтобы страница выводилась не по `/index.php?r=site/page&view=action` а по `/action/`. Подскажите как это наиболее правильно сделать, с yii ранее общаться не приходилось и пока мало что в нём понимаю.

Comment: @Deadik

> но во первых, лэйаут используется тот же что и на остальных страницах

Это потому что кое-кто не озаботился узнать, как его поменять.  
В экшене напишите `$this->layout = 'название нового лейаута'`, и будет вам счастье.

> во вторых не смог соорудить правило, чтобы страница выводилась не по ..., а по /action/

Может, все-таки сначала стоило покурить доки?

    'action' => 'site/page/view/action'

Comment: С лэйаутом разобрался, правило, как оказалось тоже цеплялось и экшн нужный вызывался, а вот с отображением вьюхи беда, отображается только верхняя часть лэйаута, при этом ошибки не выводятся, в index.php режим отладки включён. Пока ищу причины ошибки